# Update SVN credentials in jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have upgraded our instances of Jenkins(new .WAR) and it’s Subversion Plugin.
and then we come to know that it is behaving differently in the new setup.

every job must have its SVN credentials established.
In this scenario we are updating SVN credentials for each and every job for instance.

Is there any way to upgrade our SVN credentials one time for every project and for every job??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create some domain credentials in the "Manage credentials" section?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could change actual SVN credentials. It will affect all jobs that use it. The page with credentials is located here:
https://:/credentials/

I tried to find the page via menu in Jenkins configuration, but I couldn't find actual path to it.